# Conditional IBAction (if lives == 1 display "Buy Extra Lives" button)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ibaction

I currently have a button (IBAction) that I'm planning on adding an IAP feature to so the user can purchase extra lives when they're about to run out, but before I get ahead of myself I'd like to figure out how to only show this button when lives == 1 and no other time.

After hours of research and failed attempts my conclusion is that yes, you can hide a button (UIButton) with buttonName.hidden = Bool, and switch it on/off quite easily using conditional statements.

Error: (UIButton) ->() does not have a member named hidden.

But, you can't do this quite as easily (or to my knowledge, at all) using .hidden. I can clearly see the "Hidden" checkbox in the Attributes inspector for the button and if I manually check it, it will at least remain hidden when running the app, but no idea how I can invoke this with conditional code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Working with IBOutlet properties in Xcode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq-a7e_l_4I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing actions (`IBAction`) with outlets (`IBOutlet`). An action is the code that your button runs when it is tapped. An outlet is what gives you access from your code to your button. You need an *outlet*. Make an outlet from your view controller to your button. Let's call it `myButton`. Then in `viewWillAppear:` decide whether `self.myButton` should be shown or hidden, and set its `hidden` accordingly.

Comment: it IS possible I'm getting the two confused. I'm attempting to use the button for an action (press the button, either pop alert or send to a new view) and I've always used IBAction for that.

Comment: Took your advice and the button is separate from action and I can now control the button visibility with the .hidden statement and the separate IBAction I manually created then attached to the button on the storyboard handles the .alert action. Works like I needed it to, thanks.